# "How many girls did you ask their name for?"

Tags: grammar, sentence, construction

Is this question grammatically sound? It sounds slightly weird to me, and not sure if it can be paraphrased. Could somebody clarify please?

Comment: "Of how many girls did you ask their name?" Is that what you meant? Who were you asking - the girls themselves or someone else?

Comment: @ABC, Do you normally *ask for* somebody's name? *How many girls are/were there you asked their name?* *How many girls did you ask their name?*

Comment: It's asking somebody else. I want to ask the number of girls who've told him their names. And how many he has approached to ask their name. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @mahmud - So I take it my question was phrased correctly minus the "for"?

Comment: If you wanted to retain ***for***, you could reasonably ask *How many **girls' names** did you **ask for**?* Note that this (and many alternative phrasings) would often leave it ambiguous as to whether you asked the individual girls *themselves* for their names, or simply requested a list from someone else.

Comment: @ABC: yes, you can. Also you may see the comment by FumbleFingers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you, that helped. I'm surprised I didn't think of the "girls' names" version myself. I'd really appreciate it if you could share some other phrasings though.

Comment: @: Your *specific* question looks to me like it should have been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I'm half-inclined to think that strictly speaking *How many girls did you ask for their names?* might be on shaky ground by "strict grammar" (a pedant might think ***of*** was "necessary", as in ***Of** how many girls did you ask their names?* or similar). But I don't really know or care about that kind of prescriptive grammar, and I'm quite happy to agree with Blckknght (people *might* say that if disambiguation was essential, whether it's "correct" or not).

Comment: In any real conversation the information being sought is: “How many girls’ names did you get?”  Followed by a question to see how good they really are: “And how many did you ask?”

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the question makes any sense in its current form. A corrected version might be:

> How many girls did you ask for their names?

I'm not exactly sure if "names" should be plural or singular, since the number agreement is complicated in this form (since you're presumably asking each girl for just one name, her own).

The question might also work with the "for" omitted completely. Whether "for" is required, optional or forbidden may vary by dialect (I'd almost always use it myself).

Note that having "for" at the end of a question *can* work in a different context. For instance this seems perfectly valid to me as a native AmE speaker:

> How many dollars are you asking me for?

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! The way you phrased it makes perfect sense. Plural version sounds better to me even though it might not be technically correct.

Comment: I think the fact that the sentence employs "their" means it is plural "names". I suppose one could say "...did you ask for her name?". But I feel comfortable with plural throughout.  I don't however feel comfortable with no "Of" at the start, but I am British and of a certain age.

Comment: I think I'm a little less unsure of the plural "names" than my answer make it seem. The way I wrote it is definitely the best of the options available, but it's *just* awkward enough that I might prefer rephrasing the whole sentence to avoid the strange number agreement. As for a leading "of", I'd definitely not use it for the meaning I was going for where you're counting the *girls* (who you asked their own names), rather than counting names asked of some other person. But it sounds like sentence may expose even more subtle variations between dialects of English than I though!